# Is this problem correct? Can we use '$\in$' quantifier between 2 sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I got confused when saw the following problem: "$A, B, C: A \in B, B \in C, A \in C$. Do such sets exist?" Is it correct to use '$\in$' when we speak about sets, not elements? I'm new to the Set Theory so I don't know the subtleties.

Comment: Sets can be elements of other sets.  So for example if $A=\{1\}$ then it is an element of  $B=\{\{1\}\}$ and both are elements of $C=\{\{1\},\{\{1\}\}\}$.  In such a case you have $B\in C$ and $B \subset C$

Comment: oh, of course. Thank you.

Comment: $\in$ is not a quantifier, it's a relation symbol. Just saying. $\forall$ and $\exists$ are quantifiers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define what are A,B,C before. In your case, they are sets so it is correct. Here's an example:

$A = \emptyset; B = \{ \emptyset \}; C = \mathcal{P}(B) $

$A \in B, B \in C, A \in C$